# How to convert object to string without JSON.stringify using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, object, tostring

I wouldn't normally do it this way but its for a practice exercise to convert an object **without** using JSON.stringify(). The object to convert is below:

```
obj = {
  num: 0,
  string: "string",
  func: function () {},
  emptyString: '',
  null: null,
  undefined: undefined
};
```

It should produce the answer below:

```
'{"num":0,"string":"This is a string","emptyString":"","null":null}'
```

Comment: There are many `JSON.stringify` polyfills around. Just look at them to gain the insight.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` does a lot of things. Which in particular do you have problems with? Please ask a more specific question about what part you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you will always want to use `JSON.Stringify()`, but for the sake of exercise:

```
obj = {
  num: 0,
  string: "string",
  func: function () {},
  emptyString: '',
  null: null,
  undefined: undefined
};

str = Object
        .entries(obj)
        .reduce((a, e) => {
          if (typeof e[1] != "function") {
            a += `"${e[0]}" : "${e[1]}", `;
          }
          return a;
        }, "`{")
        .slice(1, -2) + "}`";

console.log(str)
```

Comment: This doesn't escape any property keys or string values.

Comment: `undefined` is not the same as `"undefined"`, and `[1, 2, 3]` will also not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = Object
    .entries(input)
    .reduce((a, e) => {
      if (typeof e[1] != "function" && e[1] !== undefined) {
        if(e[0] === "num" || e[0] === "null"){
          a += `"${e[0]}":${e[1]},`;
        } else{
        a += `"${e[0]}":"${e[1]}",`;
      }
      }
      return a;
    }, "`{")
    .slice(1, -1) + "}";
return str;
```

was able to get it with the above...though I'm sure there is a better answer. I learned that "polyfills" are what I needed to search around for from the user Bergi.

Thanks everyone who helped out